# Can we use the word "please" while throwing an error message

Tags: sentence-structure

I am trying build a software with proper error messages.

I want English words, sentence suggestion for an error message below

```
Please supply host name/IP address
```

Should we stop using the word **`Please`**,

Does the word **`Supply`** have a proper usage here?

Answer (score 3):

This reads like a good error message. 'Supply' has been used properly and adding the 'Please' makes the imperative sound less aggressive.

Answer (score 0):

They're both being used correctly, grammatically. Stylistically, using 'please' in error messages is, in my opinion, a good software choice. The only thing I would change here is that host name is conventionally one word in English, hostname. You could also say "You must supply hostname/IP address." That sounds a bit more demanding to me, and I like 'please' better.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with it either grammatically or stylistically. However, the general conventions is to say "Enter hostname/IP address." When we put information into a computer, the conventional term is "enter" rather than "supply".

There is nothing wrong with adding "please", but it is not the general convention to use it. Don't think of the message as either a request or a command. Rather, think of it as information on rectifying an error. We presume that the user wants to rectify the error, so this is something they are doing for their own sake, not yours. Saying please it therefore superfluous.

For certain kinds of information, it is worth telling the user why the information is needed. It probably does not make a difference in this case, but people have become increasingly suspicious of software asking for certain kinds of information and an honest explanation of why the information is required will do far more to get them to comply than saying please.

There are cultural difference to take into account as well, but these seem to be the general conventions in the English-speaking world.

Comment: I disagree with your "convention". When we are talking about actual user input (for instance on a form), sure, we would likely use _enter_, as in _please enter your name_. However, _supply_ is also used (although _provide_ is probably used more). _Supply_ would be just fine when one system would be making a call to another (like an API call).

Comment: The thing about conventions is that there are always counterexamples. A convention is what we usually do. But we don't always follow conventions, and the world does not end if we don't. However, technical writers and UI designers like to stick to conventions as much as possible because they are more familiar to users and provide greater consistency. Most readers will not be confused by "supply" or "provide" but a few might be, so we prefer the more conventional "enter".

Comment: But not all interfaces are **user** interfaces. Nothing in the question indicates this is an error message to be sent to a (human) end user, it may well be an error message supplied by an API or web service to a client. I would personally never "tell" a client system to "enter" anything.

Comment: Fair enough. But the example is not actually an error message. It is either a prompt or a rectification message. An API is more likely to supply an actual error message. "hostname/IP address cannot be blank" or "hostname/IP address in wrong format" or "hostname/IP address not resolved". These are all more helpful to the client system than "please supply".